# float a litle bit on top of the other

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi,

I try to create columns with album images and some info.
I want the info to overlay for a litle bit on the image next to it.
Like on this image:

However either i break floating left or the text get's totaly on top of the image etc. etc.
Like everything except the desired result.

Some help would be great, here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Scf4u/

small piece of the code:

```
<div class="entrie">
                <img class="entrieImage" src="http://doekewartena.nl/temp/images/img02.png"/>

                <div class="entrieInfo">
                    <div class="band">Kids for Cash</div>
                    <div class="album">No More Walls E.P.</div>
                    <div class="label">...</div>
                    <div class="year">1986</div>
                    <p>-</p>
                    <div class="tags">rousseau, green, woodsy, band photo, 12IN, tree, civilization, Atco, 1960's, Fuzz
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

css:

```
.entrie {
    float: left;
}

.entrieInfo {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.entrieImage {
    /* if you only set the width then the height will be set automaticly proportional*/
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Scf4u/1/

```
   #entries .entrie:nth-of-type(2n) {
            margin-left: -41px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

Should take every second .entries div and set a negative margin on the left, and a z-index to be underneath the previous div. Might have mixed up my pseudo selector.

Comment: You will have a problem in older versions of IE with that pseudo selector. Just not sure if you're going to have more than two .entrie divs :} Otherwise you can add a second/semantic class to the second entrie div and use that as a selector.

Comment: there can be a lot more then just 2 items and it will depand on wide the screen is. It could be 3x2 or 3x8 etc. Atm your solution aligns really bad on a 2nd row.

Comment: Is the content dynamic? If not you could add a .second class and use the same styles.

Answer (score 0):

Put `margin-right: -30px;` on `.enterieInfo`.

Beat by Christopher Marshall. Either or should work.

Comment: your method works better with aligment.
I only can't get the z-index done
http://jsfiddle.net/Scf4u/2/